# how to find base number in number system

Tags: algebra-precalculus

the product of 44 , 11 is 1034. what is the base of this number system ?
$$
44* *11=484 \\
1x^3+0x^2+3x^1+4x^0=484\\
x^3+3x+4=484
$$
from This equation   x = 7.7
can use base 8 in this case or base 7?

Comment: 44 and 11 are in base 10?

Comment: You seem to think that we are asking "which base makes $484_{10}$ into $1034$?" and just hiding $484$ behind an elementary arithmetic exercise. I don't think that that's it. Presumably, we are using our mystery base already when writing down $11$ and $44$.

Comment: use 44 and 11 in base 10

Comment: @emr You certain about that? Because base $7.7$ is quite exotic. It's not impossible to make sense of, but it's not in anywhere close to common use. It's more probable that $44$ and $11$ are in the unknown base.

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/in-a-number-system-the-product-of-44-and-11-is-3414-the-number-3111/ 
is same this

Answer (score 3):

Let $b$ be the base. We have $44_b = 4b+4$ and $11_b = b+1$.

Now $44_b\times11_b=1034_b \implies (4b+4)(b+1) = b^3+3b+4=(b+1)(b^2-b+4)$

As $b>4$, we have $4b+4 = b^2-b+4$, which reduces to $b^2=5b$.

Therefore $b=5$.